# Flask-Login still logged in after use logouts when using remember_me

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-login

To logout a user in flask using Flask-login, i simply call logout_user(), but after adding some additional checks with session, after I click logout and click back to "login page" again, i'm still logged in. It happens only when I choose to "remember me"

I think I misunderstand the concept of session and logout_user() here, can anyone please clarify and help?

In my opinion, i think when I clear the session then everything inside including 'user_id', 'username' etc... will also be cleared. But somehow the 'user_id' or 'username' field still exists. I think that's what causes the problem.

My Code is below:

Logout part:

```
@mod.route('/logout/')
@login_required
def logout():
  logout_user()
  session.clear()
  return redirect(url_for('users.login'))
```

Login Part:

```
@mod.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

  if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect(url_for('users.home'))

  form = LoginForm(request.form)

  if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
    if user and check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
      session['user_id'] = user.id
      session['username'] = user.nickname
      session['remember_me'] = form.remember_me.data

      remember_me = False
      if 'remember_me' in session:
          remember_me = session['remember_me']
          session.pop('remember_me', None)

      login_user(user, remember_me)

      return redirect(url_for('users.home'))
  return render_template("users/login.html", form=form)
```

Comment: Still getting this issue on 0.4.0 after so many years.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still stumbling on this... The solution is to clear the remember-me cookie.

Here's an example:

```py
@app.route('/logout', methods=['GET'])
def logout():
    flask_login.logout_user()
    session.clear()
    if session.get('was_once_logged_in'):
        del session['was_once_logged_in']

    # Delete rememberme cookie because logout_user does not do it for you.
    response = make_response(redirect(url_for('login')))
    response.delete_cookie('remember_token')
    return response
```

This is for when you're using the default cookie name for the remember-me cookie (`remember_token`.) Adapt the code with your own value if you customized the [`REMEMBER_COOKIE_NAME`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cookie-settings) setting.

My friendly advice, though, would be to just avoid Flask altogether.

Comment: Why avoid flask? And what would your friendly advice be for an alternative :)

Comment: In short: microframeworks are a fallacy. Too much time wasted looking for things that don't come with it or trying to deploy it or its libs. Flask comes with a webserver that should not be used in production so no dev-prod parity. Docs are peppered all over the place (it's flask + werkzeug + jinja). And it's supposed to be light but feels heavy (blueprints). If I were to do it again, I'd try my luck with Django or FastAPI :)

Answer (score 0):

If someone got into the same trap as i did recently:

just change the order of two strings:

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.clear()
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

meaning, first, clear the session and then, log him out.
In my case, all got working like a charm.

Answer (score -5):

When you use `Flask-Login`, you should not be updating the session dictionary yourself. You just need to provide remember_me flag to the `login_user` method and that's all. So I would suggest updating your code as the following:

```
@mod.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(url_for('users.home'))

    form = LoginForm(request.form)

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            # Just set this flag. Either True or False. 
            remember_me = False
            login_user(user, remember_me)
        return redirect(url_for('users.home'))

    return render_template("users/login.html", form=form)
```

The above code should do everything.

Comment: uuh, where is the logout part here ??