# Odd behavior with Flask App taking multiple login attempts

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I have a flask app with simple authentication that I am hosting through google cloud. I am currently testing the application by logging in and out of multiple users and I am getting some extremely weird behaviour that I wasn't previously getting. In particular, sometimes when I am logging in with a valid user account, it does nothing on the first few login attempts and then on the second or third try it will login (wtf?????). I suspect it has something to do with local storage/session storage so I am clearling local storage with session.clear() upon logging it out but it doesn't seem to be working.

Please help me because this is killing me lol. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code: main.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from . import db, create_app

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/')
def index():
     return render_template('index.html')

@main.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.html', name=current_user.name)
```

Here is the code auth.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
 from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required
from .models import User, Subs
from . import db

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login')
def login():
   return render_template('login.html')

 @auth.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
 def login_post():
    email = request.form.get('email')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    remember = True if request.form.get('remember') else False

     user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

     if not user and not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        flash('Please check your login details and try again.')
         return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

login_user(user, remember=remember)

return redirect(url_for('main.profile'))

 @auth.route('/signup')
 def signup():
     return render_template('signup.html')

 @auth.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
 def signup_post():
      email = request.form.get('email')
      name = request.form.get('name')
      password = request.form.get('password')

      user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

      if user:
          flash('Email address already exists.')
          return redirect(url_for('auth.signup'))

      new_user = User(email=email, name=name, password=generate_password_hash(password, method='sha256'))

   db.session.add(new_user)
   db.session.commit()

   return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

 @auth.route('/logout')
 @login_required
 def logout():
     logout_user()
      return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's your browser, have you tried in incognito mode?

Answer (score 0):

See this similar issue: [Flask-Login still logged in after use logouts when using remember_me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144092/flask-login-still-logged-in-after-use-logouts-when-using-remember-me)

It appears that logout_user() and session.clear() don't delete the user's cookie in their browser.

To clear the user's cookie use:

```
@app.route('/logout', methods=['GET'])
def logout():
    flask_login.logout_user()
    session.clear()
    if session.get('was_once_logged_in'):
        del session['was_once_logged_in']

# Delete rememberme cookie because logout_user does not do it for you.
response = make_response(redirect(url_for('login')))
response.delete_cookie('remember_token')
return response
```

Code taken from the response to the referred question. I have tested the code and it seems to remove the cookie from the user's browser, although I still find Flask's login very flaky....